# C# WebClient.DownloadFile returns incomplete file

Tags: c#, webclient

I've been trying to download a .rar file form google drive, and I keep bumping into the same issue over and over - file downloaded is around 1000 times less than the file on the google drive (not exaggeration).

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(address), name);
```

and

```
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(address), name);
```

give the same result, 70kb instead of 60mb.

I've spent 10 full hours roaming through the solutions on the net, including some I've seen here, none of them helped.

@Xaver basic call like this gives this outcome

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(address), name);
}
```

Comment: The HTTP response contains content-length header? Can you post the HTTP response?(*important: without authentication/cookies*)

Comment: Can you give us a minimal, reproducible example, so that we may try for ourselves?

Comment: @Leo it actually doesn't, no headers at all

Comment: All HTTP requests return headers, so that can't be true. In theory maybe there could be no headers but that's never the case in reality.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the returned file? Maybe it is html complaining about something...